# Reading file used XLSX.js with React got TypeMissMatchError on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, xlsx

I got the dialog error `TypeMissMatchError` on Internet Exlorer 11 after choosing file to read.

[image]

Below is my code to read file:

```
onChangeFile = event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", e => {
      const data = e.target.result;
      let readedData = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array", cellDates: true, dateNF: "yyyy-mm-dd;@" });

      const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];
      const dataParse = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1, raw: false, dateFN: "yyyy-mm-dd", blankrows: false, defval: "" });
      this.validateImportedData(dataParse);
      this.upload.value = "";
    });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

Any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I try to check your code and found that your code has => arrow functions.

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is not supported by the IE browser.

This can be the possible reason for that error.

You need to transpile your code from ES 6 to ES 5. Then it can work in the IE browser.

You can try to use [Babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the code. It can help you to solve the issue.

Comment: You can also write a function with a return statement if you don't want to use babeljs.

Comment: Can you please check on which line you got this error in the code? Please inform us about that line. It may help to narrow down the issue. Does this code work with other browsers? Are you only getting the issue in the IE 11 browser?

Comment: The error dialog only shows up on IE 11, If I know which line causes the problem, my question would be more specific not the whole code lines like above.

Comment: If we can see the image, it shows that error is on line number 339. Can you please check what code is on that line in that file? It may give some hint.

Comment: It's production build with minified and uglified code so I can not base on that to trace, my problem is can not run on local to trace as well :(

Comment: If possible for you then can you try to share any working sample that can produce the issue with the IE 11 browser? We are not able to run the posted code which makes it difficult to find the problematic line. Thanks for your understanding.